# How do I provide windows domain account information to OpenText Livelink ECM programmatically?

Tags: opentext

I have to implement some functionality with LiveLink 9.7 server via LLAPI (LiveLink API).

Livelink Administrator granted my Windows Domain Account permission to access LiveLink via https URL so I have to input my Windows Domain Password when I'm going to browse documents in LiveLink. So far so good.

But when it comes to program and I provide "domain\account" with "my-password" data to LLAPI Session Object it tells me that I can't connect to LiveLink Server.

Session object works well with LiveLink internal accounts (not mapped from Windows Domain).

Personally, I had no experience how Livelink Windows Domain Login <-> LiveLink User Mapping is implemented. How shall I provide my identity information to LiveLink server programmatically or what extra information I have to ask LiveLink administrator ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First you should ask the LL admin what is your login name. Windows AD accounts can be synchronized with LL using login names like "DOMAIN\username", "username" or other patterns. Make sure that your account is allowed to log in.

You can also use NTLM SSO that is supported by LAPI if you run your application in an authenticated Windows session.